# Does GNU Global support objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

I googled but there's no answer... I have tried etags but I wonder if there's any more equivalent. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn’t say it does. Why don’t you just try what you get when you let it run on Objective-C code?

Answer (score 1):

Old thread but still top search result using google. So lets answer the question: "yes" it can - see http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/gcc_5.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure. and I'm trying to do same.

But in other website, (official global forum?) they say "Yes, if you use plugin".

http://old.nabble.com/Objective-C-support--td29162808.html